# How to Simply and Selectively Eliminate the Page Number of an Index Entry

Tags: pdftex, indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, idxlayout

I have learned that one may selectively make bold the page number of an Index entry by the use of `|textbf` at the end of the `\index` command.

For example, consider

```
\documentclass{book}
\textwidth=6.75in \oddsidemargin-25pt \evensidemargin=-35pt
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage %clears all blank pages; must come before \makeindex!
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\LARGE

\newpage A sentence.\index{\textbf{Eliminate Page $\#$}@!Comma shift@\textcolor{red}{Instead of a bold page $\#$, is there an analogous way to selectively \textbf{\textit{eliminate it}}---and the comma as well?}|textbf}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the following index entry:

[image]

QUESTION: Is there a similar simple way to *eliminate* the page number (and associated comma) of an index entry as well? I ask because I have encountered certain situations where the page number is not useful, and so I would like to selectively eliminate it.

Thank you.

Comment: What are these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a horrible kludge, but hey, it works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\killnext#1{}

\begin{document}
A sentence.\index{\textbf{Eliminate Page $\#$}@!Comma
shift@\textcolor{red}{Instead of a bold page $\#$, is there an analogous way
to selectively \textbf{\textit{eliminate it}}---and the comma as
well?\aftergroup\killnext}|killnext}

Another sentence.\index{\textbf{Eliminate Page $\#$}@!Comma
shift@\textcolor{red}{Use a bold page $\#$}|textbf}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you once again for a very helpful answer.